# Vertically Center Last Column of tabularx

Tags: vertical-alignment, tabularx

How do you vertically center the last column of a `tabularx` table?

I tried to create a custom column, though, TBH, I don't really know what I'm doing.

Basically, I'd like the contents of the left and right columns to aligned in the same way, both vertically and horizontally. What do I need to do to they `y` type column? I want to use `\m{}` of some type, but am not sure how.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{17cm}{|C{8cm}|Y|} \hline

\tikz{
\draw (0,0)--(4,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
 \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
\foreach \x in {0,...,3} 
 \draw[-latex] (\x+0.1,-0.15)--(\x+0.9,-0.15);
\node at (2,-0.8) {4};
} &
\tikz{
\draw (0,0)--(6,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}
 \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 \draw[-latex] (\x+0.1,-0.15)--(\x+0.9,-0.15);
 \node at (3,-0.8) {6};}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Heiko has answered the question but really tabularx is doing nothing useful here. Why not just use `\begin{tabular}{cc}` and arrange the vertical allignment with tikz? Actually if it is really one row in the actual document you don't need tabularr either, just two tikz environments.

Comment: @ David Carlisle, I'm still a bit of a `LaTeX` newb, so I'm not sure how to space the columns in `\begin{tabular}` properly. `tabularx` seemed to help a lot with that, though. Also, there will be quite a few more rows. I included only one for the MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `tabularx` uses `\tabularxcolumn` for the column type of `X` columns. The default is `p{#1}`. It can be redefined to match the other `m` column:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{tabularx}{17cm}{|C{8cm}|Y|} \hline
\tikz{
\draw (0,0)--(4,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,4}
 \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
\foreach \x in {0,...,3}
 \draw[-latex] (\x+0.1,-0.15)--(\x+0.9,-0.15);
\node at (2,-0.8) {4};
} &
\tikz{
\draw (0,0)--(6,0);
\foreach \x in {0,...,6}
 \draw (\x,-0.3)--(\x,0.3);
\foreach \x in {0,...,5}
 \draw[-latex] (\x+0.1,-0.15)--(\x+0.9,-0.15);
 \node at (3,-0.8) {6};}
\\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Awesome! It worked perfectly. I'm not sure *how* it worked, though. My guess is that your `\renewcommand*{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}` renewed ONLY the vertical alignment of the X column. Is that right? My other question is what is the asterisk here for?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything Package `tabularx` uses `\tabularxcolumn` for the internal column format of its `X` columns. The default is `p{#1}`. It can be changed by redefining to `\m{#1}`. `#1` is a length and should not contain whole paragraphs (`\par`). The star form of `\newcommand` forbids these `\par` tokens. If the ending curly brace is forgotten for the argument, then TeX will already stop at the next empty line or `\par` token to throw the error and does not have to wait for the end of file.